# Where did the volume control options go in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer, mixer, feature-regression

XP's `sndvol32` sound mixer  used to feature individual volume controls such as `Wave`, `SW Synth` and `CD Player`, `PC Speaker` or `PCM SPDIF` among others. These could be set hidden or visible under it's menu Options / properties / (device) / playback .

[image: sndvol32 options properties playback volume controls cd player sw synth]

With Windows 7's `sndvol` now it looks like this, with **no** menu, **no** options, **no** properties, **no** such volume controls:

[image: sndvol windows 7 volume controls]

**edit 1(** I tried to check under control panel / sound, there is a tab for 'playback' and one for 'recording', among others, which seem to happen to named like XP's options/properties checkboxes. But the other volume controls are missing, with only Speaker and Headphones available in the playback list, either which didn't seem to correspond to the "Wave" control anyway. **)edit 1**

I cannot find a way to add the missing controls. and enabled hidden devices, but couldn't find these controls. Maybe I've just missed something. Most of them did *not* used to be any special, they were handled by the general drivers/OS.

**Where did those previous controls go and how can I set them?**

Comment: They changed it.  Each application can be turned now.

Comment: Click on the speaker icon and you'll get all/most of your sound card driver's options.  I can mute my Input Monitor from in there, under a "levels" tab, for example.

Comment: @Ramhound yes I can understand *that* however I cannot see that any application should correspond to "midi synthetizer" or "CD Player" and definitely not "PC speaker", if you got what I mean. For example, cd player is either an analog or a digital data transmit from the physical CD drive to the motherboard or the OS. The analog one uses a cable. Definitely no application owns it exclusively. The midi synthetizer can be a software or a chip on your sound card, among others; no application should exclusively own that either.

Comment: @techie007 well that only gives a single slider for me, my Speakers. But you point to this idea, I right clicked the tray icon and got "playback devices". However if this supposed to be the equivalent of options/properties/playback, then I cannot see where particular devices did go. I have no synthetizer, no cd audio, only speakers and headphones. This doesn't seem to correspond with the XP way since there it wouldn't be any different if you attached speakers or headphones, however you got a separate control for synth, etc. I tried to right click or find a button to add devices, without luck.

Comment: @naxa - If you have an audio disk in the "CD Player" then software is playing the music and would be listed which means you can tune the levels for that given application.

Comment: I remember an old time, I had to mute "CD Player" otherwise I was hearing some constant buzz (particularly noticeable when no sound playing). Muting "CD Player" solved the issue (what a relief). I wish I could still do it nowadays, just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

In your Windows 7 screenshot, there is a downwards arrow next to 'Speakers'. Click on that and there should be options for different output devices or input devices. I am not sure if this is what you specifically want, but this should show every input/output it is using.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the speaker button in the taskbar (the one you painted big red arrow for). Select Recording devices. Enable hidden, select one and click the **Properties** button.

Also reachable as Control Panel->Sound->Recording tab.

Now, in recording device properties, go to **Listen** tab. This is different from *WindowsXP*. Check **"Listen to device"** and **Apply**.

Comment: I think now I understand, maybe this could be combined with EdG's answer. Why this had to be changed, the new way is so much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Some of those extra volume controls appear on the "Levels" tab of "Playback device" "Properties". But only after installing proper drivers; Realtek drivers in my case:
[image]

And yes, I needed those controls to get rid of "CD Audio" noise.